# Excel VBA: Trying to create UDF "UseIF" - Wanting a UDF to return the left portion of an expression if the evaluation is true

Tags: excel, vba, user-defined-functions

In Excel, I often have complicated formulas where I need to know if the result of an expression is true before I use the value.  Often times, I have to put the result in a separate cell, and then use that result in another calculation / formula.

I would like to create a UDF that allowed me to pass:

Function UseIf(left_expression, comparison_expression, value_if_false)

If the overall item is true, I want to return the value for the left expression, much the same way that IfError() returns the evaluation if it doesn't yield an error.  Here, I want to return the evaluation if it meets another criteria.  I want to pass in the matching criteria or comparison expression, much like you do in SUMIIF, etc.  Then for good measure, accept a value to return if the comparison is false.

Yes, in Excel, I can simply create an Excel formula (in the worksheet) with an IF statement and I include the entire expression if the If Test and in the If Results, but that generates a lot of duplication in a formula.

I tried having the UDF insert the expressions as range.formula for cells in my Personal.xlsb, to have excel do the expression parsing & calculation for me.  But Excel won't allow a UDF to update another cell's value or formula (it always goes to my OnError condition - The same functionality works in a macro subroutine, but not in a udf.)  Also, I seem to run into a lot of problems with volatility in UDFs, with it recalculating much more often than I think it should.  If it didn't recalculate when anything on the spreadsheet was updated, then the idea of using temporary cells and updating the associated formulas might work (if Excel allowed me to that is).  However, if it is volatile, then the cells might have different values in them at a later point.

Any ideas?  Is this possible?  Or do I have to stick with long and messy simple IF statements?

Update:  Thanks to Scott's help, I came up with the following solution.  Please let me know if you see anything that needs improvement.  Thanks again!

```
Function UseIf(left_expression As Variant, _
           comparison_expression As Variant, _
           Optional value_if_false As Variant, _
           Optional value_if_error As Variant) As Variant

    Dim vResult As Variant
    
    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

    If (Not InStr("=><", Left(comparison_expression, 1)) > 0) Then comparison_expression = "=" & comparison_expression
    If IsMissing(value_if_false) Then value_if_false = ""
    
    vResult = Evaluate(left_expression)

    UseIf = IIf(Evaluate(vResult & comparison_expression), vResult, value_if_false)
    
Exit Function

ErrorHandler:
    UseIf = IIf(Not IsMissing(value_if_error), value_if_error, "#ERROR")

End Function
```

Comment: You can use Worksheet.Evaluate to evaluate a string that looks like a formula then test the outcome and return the correct output.

Comment: BTW if you have Office 365 you can use `LET` which allows the use of variables: `LET(x,B1+B2,IF(x=3,x,"not"))`  Which is not volatile.

Comment: Accepting that you can only return a value (or values) from a UDF, it's unclear exactly what the problem is.  As far as I'm aware Excel uses the same recalculation rules for UDF's as it does for regular formulas, so your UDF should not be "worse" in that respect.  Can you show an actual example of what you're dealing with?

Comment: Can LAMBDA be used in this case? (It is announced released but does not seems available yet on my monthly/preview version)

Comment: Thank you Scott!  
Evaluate was exactly what I was looking for.  With that, it becomes a very simple function,  
I appreciate your help!